# Does Reporting Services 2008 support multiple datasources for a single object?

Tags: reporting-services, datasource, ssrs-2008

i.e. Can you have more than one data source in a table, or do you still need to use subreports if you want that functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No

http://blogs.technet.com/sqlman/archive/2009/03/01/reporting-services-combining-different-datasets-to-be-displayed-in-a-single-table-in-ssrs.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I've developed a couple of new dashboard-like reports in SSRS 2008 recently and I had to use subreports.

Comment: But was that because you wanted to or because 2008 does not support this functionality? Please provide a link to anything that supports this.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple datasources specified at the Report Definition level.  Your table can use all of them.

Comment: This functionality is not available in RS2005. Can you show any evidence of this, articles, screenshots etc? To demonstrate that this new functionality was introduced in RS2008

Comment: Then, just merge all the datasets into a larger new one.

Comment: I did not ask for workarounds or alternatives. I just want a simple yes/no with a link to evidence of such functionality or lack of. If RS2008 has this feature then we get to upgrade :)

Comment: Well, I managed to add multiple datasources in RS2005.

Try it, it works.

Comment: Not for a single object it doesn't. You cannot have a single table consuming two datasources.